# Maximization of a nasty Gaussian likelihood

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a Gaussian likelihood function,
$$p(y|x) = \mathcal{N}(y; Ax, (x^\top V x + \lambda) \otimes I)$$
where $A,V,\lambda$ is known, and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. (the notation indicates that covariance is a scalar times identity matrix -- scalar is: $x^\top V x + \lambda$). Note that $A$ is a rectangular matrix, say $m\times n$ with $m>n$. I would like to maximise this with respect to $x$, in other words, solve the following problem,
$$x^* = \arg \max_x p(y|x) = \arg \max_x \mathcal{N}(y;Ax,(x^\top V x + \lambda) \otimes I)$$
I tried to take derivative of the log-likelihood and set it to zero, however I was unable to leave out $x$ and obtain an exact solution.

I wonder if there is an exact solution, and if not: what the best numerical scheme is to overcome this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*PS*: Pseudoinverse is not the solution, according to numerical examples! And another empirical observation from 2d simulations: As $\lambda \to \infty$ (for very large values), pseudoinverse solution becomes more and more accurate, so this hints about structure of the solution a bit.

PS2: As $\lambda \to \infty$, the solution is the following,
$$x^* = (d (C^\top C)^{-1} V + I)^{-1} (C^\top C)^{-1} C^\top y$$
where $d = \dim(y)$. I don't know how it is useful though...

Comment: Is $Ax$ the mean (vector) of the density and $(x^\top V x + \lambda) \otimes I$ the covariance matrix?  I am unfamiliar with the notation $\mathcal{N}(\cdot; \cdot, \cdot)$.

Comment: Yes exactly. $\mathcal{N}(y;\mu,\Sigma)$ means, density is defined over $y$ with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$.

Comment: The log likelihood is going to have a term which is the ratio of quadratics in $x$, so I would guess an exact solution is hard to come by. But try a couple of examples, in 1 or 2 dimensions, and see if there is a pattern that extends to higher dimensions. As to numerical approximations, I would guess that BFGS or some variant of it would be suitable. Again, it might be insightful to take a look at contours in low dimensional examples.

Comment: Yes. I already plotted some low dimensional examples, its behaviour is changing with $\lambda$ but in general it is nonconvex (have two modes in 1-dim, I'm not sure for 2-dim). Somebody said may be it can be solved by a reparametrization, so I posted this.

Comment: @oeda - Is the matrix $A$ given as invertible?

Comment: No it is not even square. (I had to state it, my fault). Just saw your solution, thanks! but I guess it is not generalisable to nonsquare case?

Comment: I think it is generalizable, see added comment.  But it would take even more work.

Comment: Thanks! I will work through the details. May I thank you if I use this solution in the paper? as an anonymous user? :-)

Answer (score 0):

We want to maximize the log likelihood function 
$$L(x) = \ln{p(y|x)} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln((x^TVx + \lambda)^n) - 
\frac{1}{2}\frac{||y - Ax||^2}{(x^TVx + \lambda)} - \frac{n}{2}\ln{2\pi}$$

Assume that $A$ is invertible and define new variables: $z = y - Ax$.  In this parametrization $x = A^{-1}(y - z)$ and
$$L(z) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(((A^{-1}(y - z))^TV(A^{-1}(y - z)) + \lambda)^n) - 
\frac{1}{2}\frac{||z||^2}{((A^{-1}(y - z))^TV(A^{-1}(y - z)) + \lambda)} - \frac{n}{2}\ln{2\pi}$$
For simplicity, define $M(y, z) = (A^{-1}(y - z))^TV(A^{-1}(y - z)) + \lambda$.  Dropping the constant we have
$$L(z) = -\frac{n}{2}\ln(M(y,z)) - \frac{1}{2}\frac{||z||^2}{M(y, z)}$$

For later:
$$\frac{d}{dz_i} M(y, z) = 2\delta_i(A^{-1})^TVA^{-1}(z - y) = 2\delta_iN(z - y)$$
where I have set $N = (A^{-1})^TVA^{-1}$ (for future brevity) and $\delta_i$ is the standard $i$th row vector.

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dz_i} L(z) &=& \frac{d}{dz_i} \left(-\frac{n}{2}\ln(M(y,z)) - \frac{1}{2}\frac{||z||^2}{M(y, z)}\right) \\
&=& -\frac{n}{2}\frac{\frac{d}{dz_i}M}{M} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(2z_i)M - ||z||^2\frac{d}{dz_i}M}{M^2}\right) \\
&=& \frac{-1}{M}\left(\frac{n}{2}(2\delta_iN(z - y)) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(2z_i) - ||z||^22\delta_iN(z - y)}{M}\right)\right) \\
&=& \frac{-1}{M}\left(n(\delta_iN(z - y)) + \left(\frac{(z_i) -||z||^2\delta_iN(z - y)}{M}\right)\right) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, after some algebra, we find that
$$nM\delta_iN(z - y) + z_i - ||z||^2 \delta_iN(z - y) = 0$$
Rearranging terms we obtain
$$z_i = (||z||^2 - nM)\delta_iN(z - y)$$

Comment: is it possible that solution is $x = (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top y$, what do you think? I say this completely with a gut feeling, but normally the problem is least squares if we don't have $x$ in the covariance, and the solution is this (and yours). Is it possible that somehow covariance is irrelevant in the maximisation? (I am intentionally being vague)

Comment: @oeda  Yes, that is almost the answer I am suggesting for the general case.  I found a formula for it on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29  Scroll down to the section on Orthogonal Projections:  $$x = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$$

Comment: great! let me check also the details above. thanks a million!

Comment: @oeda - I'm looking at that section closer and it is just for matrices $A$ whose columns are orthogonal.  In any event, I am suggesting the solution would be
$$\arg \min_x ||y - Ax||^2$$

Comment: Yes that is the applying pseudoinverse, i.e. $x = (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top y$. I also think that. Thanks a million again!

Comment: I tried this for 2-dimensional examples, plotted the contour of the likelihood wrt $x$, and also plot the analytical solution we suggest. Unfortunately, it is usually too far from the true maxima. So... I still have a problem :)

Comment: @oeda - Was the counterexample you found for an invertible $A$?

Comment: No, as I said, I'm trying for nonsquare $A$ matrices, the counterexample was with $3\times 2$ matrix. So I'm not saying that the proof is wrong for invertible $A$, what I'm saying our suggestion in comments seems wrong. (Also I found an error in my proof that $\lambda \to \infty$ makes solution the pseudoinverse -- trying to work on it).

Comment: @oeda - Found an error in the derivation. See update above.  I'm more satisfied with this one.  Regarding your above question, I do think there should be interplay between the variance matrix and the mean matrix.